# File input sending null to controller

Tags: c#, html, forms, file, razor

I have a file input inside of a form. Ideally I'd like it to allow uploading multiple files on form submit. It was sending empty list so I tried changing to just receive a single file, now it's sending null.

My cshtml form:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm(nameof(ServiceCallController.AddMessage), "ServiceCall", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.Label("New Message")
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11">
                @Html.Kendo().EditorFor(m => m.NewMessage).Tools(t => t.Clear())
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.Label("Attachments")
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11">
                <input type="file"
                       id="myFile"
                       name="myFile"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.Kendo().Button().Content("Add Message").Name("SubmitAddMessage")
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

My controller method:

```
    public ActionResult AddMessage(int id, string newMessage, HttpPostedFileBase myFile)
    {
        if (myFile == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myFile));//This should not happen
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(MyView), new { id });
    }
```

And the contents being sent in the network tab request form data:

```
Id: 5473
NewMessage: Why is this not working?
myFile: Chrysanthemum.jpg
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is my file not being sent to the controller?

Comment: @devNull Yes. I didn't see that in the list of suggested Questions when writing this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add enctype as `multipart/form-data`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(nameof(ServiceCallController.AddMessage), "ServiceCall", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

And the action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMessage(int id, string newMessage, HttpPostedFileBase myFile)
{
    if (myFile == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myFile));//This should not happen
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(MyView), new { id });
}
```